# GCM on app and on aar. Push notifications sent to the aar are also received by the app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've created an library project that uses GCM to receive push notifications. While installed this library on an app that **does not** have push notifications enabled, I'm receiving and parsing the push notifications as expected.

The problem is if the app itself has an implementation of GCM.

I've faced an issue that pushes sent to my library were not received. This was because the library was also registered in the manifest to `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver`. To overcome this, in my library, I've created an class that extends `GcmReceiver` and register it in my library manifest. Something like:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".gcm.CustomPushNotificationsReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!--For pre-4.4 KitKat devices-->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In `CustomPushNotificationsReceiver` in `onReceive` I check the `from` field in the `Intent` and if it is destined to my library, I start the service in my library responsible for receiving push notifications.

This approach has some faults.
1 - In `CustomPushNotificationsReceiver` I also receive pushes destined to the app thus getting access to it's contents (the app that is using my library may not want this).
2 - Pushes sent to my library are also received by the app thus the app has to verify if the push received is destined to her.

I can override issue 2 if the app itself gets registered to `CustomPushNotificationsReceiver`. `CustomPushNotificationsReceiver` will than handle the pushed if they are for the app or the library. But this does not solve issue 1.

Is it possible to "mark" the push messages so that they are only received by the package they are destined to?

Comment: "so that they are only received by the package they are destined to?" -- from the standpoint of GCM, libraries do not exist. The only "packages" are the apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. So, from your point of view, the best approach is to both app and library register the `CustomPushNotificationsReceiver`?

Comment: IMHO, the best approach is for there to be only one GCM receiver per app. Your library can offer a receiver for apps that do not use GCM themselves. For apps that do use GCM, you need to support some way that the app can register for GCM itself, then forward messages to your library that are of relevance to the library. I would not assume that GCM itself will necessarily invoke N receivers for an app (e.g., yours + app's = 2). Even if that works today, that might not work tomorrow.